# PostgresSQL query for matching a subset of criteria

Tags: database, postgresql

Is there a good way of writing a PostgreSQL query for matching a subset of criteria?

To give an example:
In a database, I have a table of student records that has fields:
`Name`, `Age`, `Gender`, `Year`, `Grade`.
Now, I have three criteria: `Age > 15`, `Gender == Male`, `Year > 8` and I want the results that match either two of them.

For me, it will be a nightmare if I want to match any 8 out of 10 criteria as  I have to concatenate all combinations with `OR`.

Is there a more practical way to write that query in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may sum your various boolean conditions after casting them to integers:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM yourTable
WHERE (Age > 15)::int + (Gender = Male)::int + (Year > 8)::int >= 2;
```

Above we are requiring that at least 2 of the 3 conditions have a integer value of 1 (meaning 2 of 3 are true).